# The amplification factor of the EMG circuit did not meet expectations

Tags: amplifier, ecg, medical

I've recently embarked on a project to create a DIY EMG system and have been using Multisim for simulation purposes before finalizing the PCB design. Attached is an image of my EMG circuit. In this design, the raw signal is first amplified by a factor of 100 using the INA128. Following this, it goes through a bandpass filter, which results in an amplification factor of only 3. Subsequently, I attempted to further amplify the signal. According to the formula, the amplification factor should equal 1*R16/R17，which theoretically should result in a 5-fold increase. However, I've only managed to achieve a 2-fold amplification. Could anyone provide insight into why this discrepancy exists? Additionally, if you have any suggestions or improvements for other parts of the circuit, I would greatly appreciate your advice.

[image]

---

I have updated my design at the first stage. Based on everyone's suggestions and the document released by Texas Instruments, is this design a good idea?

[image]
[image]

I have acquired my test PCB board, but I haven't got what I wanted. Upon inspection, I believe it's a fault in the power supply system. When I supply it with 3.3V, the measured supply voltage is actually only around 1.1V. In other words, the sensors cannot work at all. Can anyone provide some solutions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should obtain a gain of (1+R16/R17) ... yes, but you have already a voltage input of 1.596 V at MM3. Multiplied by 5.xxx ... you saturate the output of U5.

Comment: Yes, that was an issue, and I overlooked it. The problem has now been resolved, thank you.

Comment: Why did you use 250 MOhm and 250 mOhm (R1 and R2) at the inputs of INA128 ? You don't have return path for the bias of inputs.

Comment: The initial design aimed to maximize input impedance, but I found that this led to a reduced amplification factor of the output signal. To maintain a 100-fold amplification in the first stage, I reduced the input impedance.

Comment: The current bias is +/- 2 nA. You could use some 1 -> 10 MegOhm resistors wired to the ground of INA128.

Comment: Look up "AC-coupled front-end for biopotential measurements" by E.M. Spinelli, it describes in detail a very good biopotential amplifier, I have used it before and it is very capable for EMG, ECG, EOG and even EEG. You can replace almost the entire first stage with the INA128 because it's internal construction matches Spinelli's circuit. The circuit is so good, that you should not even need additional band filtering. Here is a link to my university project which describes the usage of this circuit: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TCMjzAOU_vE8G8pkrsgR9de9TbcFch0X/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, I will look into them.

Comment: What are the cutoffs of your band-pass??

Comment: I think it will be 20-450Hz. I using fliter design tool（developer is ADI）to do that.

Comment: Should be ok now. Test it and keep informed of results.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have finalized the PCB design and dispatched it to the factory for SMT assembly. I plan to conduct initial tests on an Arduino and will keep updated with the outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

From this datasheet [INA128](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina128.pdf?ts=1707655000258)

Have a look also at this [note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa503/sboa503.pdf?ts=1707729227203&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fds%252Fsymlink%252Fina128.pdf%253Fts%253D1707655000258)

You should provide a return path for the bias inputs of INA128

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will do some research to solve this issue.

Comment: Hello sir, I have updated my design. Can you take a look at the new circuit design?